# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool, ¿Que debo arreglar?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin, fetch

Trato de hacer una validación de datos según una base en xampp, con dos carcateres de informacion, siendo usuario y contraseña, si coinciden se manda a otra pagina, si no se manda un mensaje, a la hora de escribir la información correcta me imprime el Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool en la línea nueve, el fetch object().
¿Como soluciono este error, he buscado y no encuentro forma ya que el que me base si le funciona, se que esta devolviendo un false.
[image: Error al dar clic en el boton] Codigo de error en linea 9:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["mandar"])){
    if(empty($_POST["nom"]) and empty($_POST["con"])){
        echo "Los campos estan vacios o son incorrectos";
    }else{
        $Nombre=$_POST["nom"];
        $Pass =$_POST["con"];
        $sql=$conexion->Query("select * from administrador where nom='$Nombre' and con='$Pass' ");
        if ($datos=$sql->fetch_object()) {
            header("location: ../index.html");
        } else {
            echo"Acceso denegado";
        }
        
    }
}

?>
```

Código de base de datos:

```
<?php

$conexion=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "cofcat");
$conexion->set_charset("utf8");

?>
```

Comment: No estás incluyendo el archivo de la conexión, sin eso la consulta no funcionará nunca, aunque sea correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error lo devuelve el método `fetch_objetc()` porque la consulta que lanzas en con el método `query()` no devuelve ningún resultado.

Antes de hacer el `fetch_object()` deberías asegurarte que la propiedad `$sql->num_rows` es positiva. Es decir, que la consulta ha devuelto algún registro.

Sería algo así:

En vez de:

```
if ($datos=$sql->fetch_object())
```

Utiliza:

```
if ($sql->num_rows())
```

Obtendrás el comportamiento que esperas de tu código, pero sin el mensaje de error que recibes actualmente.

Por otra parte y sobre todo en un login, utiliza los métodos `prepare()`, `bind_param()` y `execute()` para lanzar una consulta preparada, en vez de `query()` y así evitar ataques por inyección de código.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.